Rails numericality validation does not work when using symbol
I have the following validation in my 'config' model:
validates :property_value_max, numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_nil: true }

and it works if I try to update it like (in the sense that it does not allow setting it to string):
config.update(property_value_max: 'foobar')
config.errors_full_messages

# ["Property value max is not a number"]

However if I update to a symbol, it simply sets it to nil
config.update(property_value_max: :foobar)
config.errors.full_messages
# []
config.property_value_max
# nil

How do I avoid this? I still want to allow explicitly setting the value to nil, but I don't want to have this automatic conversion of symbol to nil...

Why would you set it to a symbol at all? The purpose of validations is to catch most invalid user input and provide feedback.  Not to prevent developers from doing silly things.

That is could be due to typecasting ActiveRecord does when updating the record with older versions of Ruby. And since there's the allow_nil: true there, a symbol converted to int will result in a nil, which is saved successfully.
A simple validator (or a pre-save hook, whatever is better for your case) should help:
class Config < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validate :ensure_not_symbol

  private

  def ensure_not_symbol
    if property_value_max.is_a?(Symbol)
      errors.add(:property_value_max, 'cannot be a symbol')
    end
  end
end


If you really think you need this you should actually just raise an exception here as your program should not be assigning a symbol in the first place.
